# How to display a cell value corresponding to its input from another cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this kinda dataframe:

```
A  B  C  D  E
0  1  5  0  0
   2  3  1  0
   3  5  0  7
1  1  3  1  2
   3  3  3  3
2  5  1  2  1
```

If user input `A = 0`, `B = 2`, I need to show `C = 3` `D = 1` and `E = 0` OR \n

If user input `A = 1`, `B = 1`, I need to show `C = 3` `D = 1` and `E = 2`

Comment: `df.loc[(df["A"] == 0) & (df["B"] == 2), ["C", "D", "E"]]` will do selection for you. You should take a look at the [indexing and selecting data guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: If A and B are called from user to input, then it didn't work, please add on this, i'll be grateful.

Comment: Sounds like the are strings not integers.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple selection:

```
df.query('(A==0) & (B==1)')[['C', 'D', 'E']]
```

Comment: If A and B are called from user to input, then it didn't work, please add on this, i'll be grateful.